# jQuery How to stop functions so they happen one at a time

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form where a user can enter a page title into an input field and it will generate a URL. On the submit button click the value is displayed in a different input field(URL). If they are not happy with their URL they can manually edit it inside that field and then save their changes via a button click.

The button's value also changes depending on the state of the URL field.

My code is working but I have a problem with the last 2 functions happening at once, I have tried adding StopEventPropagation (or similar) and that has not worked for me. Please help if you can.

The [JSfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/8xruN/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than combining both handlers I used jQuerys [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler for the second click.

```
$("input#page_url_button.edit_url_button").live('click', function () {
      alert("2");
      $(this).val("Save");
      $("input#page_url").removeAttr("disabled");
      $(this).removeClass("edit_url_button");
      $(this).addClass("save_url_button");
});
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/dJPvJ/

**Edit:**

I was half-way there with my original answer, this amended code should do what you need:

```
// If URL has info in it, then change value of button and add class to button
$("input#page_url_button.save_url_button").live('click', function () {
if( $("input#page_url").val().length > 0 ) {
      $(this).val("Edit URL");
      $(this).addClass("edit_url_button");
}
}); // This part is getting skipped, I need to find a way to include this in the process


// If this button has class (edit_button_url) change value, add new class and remove the Dsiabled attr from URL field
$("input#page_url_button.edit_url_button").live('click', function () {
      $(this).val("Save");
      $("input#page_url").removeAttr("disabled");
      $(this).removeClass("edit_url_button");
      $(this).addClass("save_url_button");
});
```

To get this to work you also need to add "save_url_button" to the original markup:

```
<input id="page_url_button" type="button" value="Submit" class="save_url_button fright" style="width:60px">
```

Comment: Thanks this is very close, I could see the second button state, when the alert was triggered but it disapeared after I closed the Alert box

Comment: I've modified the fiddle so both handlers use 'live' and I've added the `save_url_button` class to the original button. Check it out and see if it does what you want now.

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't see the changes you mentioned in the fiddle, can you post the js here in the comment pls. Thanks

Comment: I've forked that fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/m8z9d/ That definitely has the latest code. I'll edit my answer above accordingly.

Comment: Hi @John Keyes, just one more question, the ---
var text = $("input#page_title").val();
      $("input#page_url").val(text); --- function runs everytime I click the button, is there anyway to get this to only run on the first function? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still runs each time, basically I click "Edit URL" and change the text in the URL input field. When I click on "Save" it overwrites my new text in the URL input field, any ideas? Thanks so much for all your help, cheers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3910/discussion-between-john-keyes-and-clinton-green)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in JavaScript or jquery to guarantee a priority for event order. I would recommend trying to change the 2nd event function to a normal function and calling it at the end of the 1st

```
function clickhandler(event)
{
   //do stuff
   //...
   clickhandler2(event);
}

function clickhandler2(event)
{
   //do stuff
   //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried that originally, had all three broken up into separate functions, I gave your suggestion a go too but it still skipped the second function.

Comment: instead of using $(this) in your function declare a variable to var button = $("input#page_url_button"); I suspect that the function is being called but $(this) is not pointing to what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Last 2 functions fire together because you assigned them as a click handler **to the same element**.

consider the following JS:
**I've combined bodies of both functions to 1. They will execute one after another now.**

```
// Display entered text in URL field on submit
    $("input#page_url_button").click(function () {
      var text = $("input#page_title").val();
      $("input#page_url").val(text);
    });


// If URL has info in it, then change value of button and add class to button
    $("input#page_url_button").click(function () {
    if( $("input#page_url").val().length > 0 ) {
          $(this).val("Edit URL");
          $(this).addClass("edit_url_button");
    }

    if( $(this).hasClass('edit_url_button') ) {
          $(this).val("Save");
          $("input#page_url").removeAttr("disabled");
          $(this).removeClass("edit_url_button");
          $(this).addClass("save_url_button");
    }

    }); // This part is getting skipped, I need to find a way to include this in the process
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying but the Edit URL state (2nd function) is still getting skipped

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/99eSJ/1/) what you're looking for:

```
$("input#page_url_button").click(function() {
    // Display entered text in URL field on submit
    var text = $("input#page_title").val();
    $("input#page_url").val(text);
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit_url_button')) {
        $(this).removeClass("edit_url_button");
        $(this).addClass("save_url_button");
        alert('Saved!');
        $(this).val("Submit");
        $("input#page_url").val('').attr('disabled', 'dsabled');
    }
    else if ($("input#page_url").val().length > 0) {
        $('input#page_title').val("Edit URL");
        $(this).addClass("edit_url_button");
        $(this).val("Save");
        $("input#page_url").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: After the comment of @Clinton Green to my answer - I see whats the problem is. And looks like you solved it already :) +1

Comment: Hi, thanks but it wasn't quite what I was looking for, it was getting close though, I played around with your code for a bit and tried to get it to work how I wanted but but wasn't able to, cheers